# mod_rewrite writing local routes

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

You see, I want to redirect [R] from http://www.domain.com/dir1/ to http://www.domain.com/.

I also want to accept http://www.domain.com/dir1/([0-9]+) and [L] those requests to dir1.php?query=$1. And to [L] all http://www.domain.com/dir1/(.+) to the root.

So these are my rules:

```
RewriteRule dir1/([0-9]+) dir1.php?query=$1 [L]
RewriteRule dir1/(.+) $1 [L]
RewriteRule dir1/ . [R,L]
```

The problem with the last one (and I tried many variations of it) is that redirects to http://www.domain.com/home/domain/www/. I mean, that inserts the local directory. I just want it to redirect to http://www.domain.com/

Thanks,

Comment: Are these at the top level in your httpd.conf?

Comment: No, they are in /home/domain/www/.htaccess

Comment: I guess that what I am asking is how to force mod_rewrite to do a URI-based substitution. (avoid the use of local paths)

Comment: (( Argh, I just noticed I had rewrite logging turned on on my webserver, since January ... ! ))

Comment: For a redirect, try putting a full URL on the right hand side. http:// etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a path with a slash to redirect the client to some absolute path.

```
RewriteRule dir1/ /  [R,L]
```

The mistake is using `.` instead of `/`.

This comes straight from the RewriteRule examples:

```
Inside per-directory configuration for /somepath
(/physical/path/to/somepath/.htacccess, with RewriteBase /somepath)
for request ``GET /somepath/localpath/pathinfo'':

Given Rule                                      Resulting Substitution
----------------------------------------------  ----------------------------------

[... snip ...]

^localpath(.*) /otherpath$1                     /otherpath/pathinfo
```

In our case `/otherpath` is just `/` and we don't use `$1` since we don't want the local part.

You can also redirect using absolute URLs. That is useful for redirecting http requests to https or going to other websites. You can redirect to the same server like this:

```
RewriteRule dir1/ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/  [R,L]
```

But this is needlessly complicated.

Comment: Thanks, That's a nice thing. But two question: 1) what about if I want to keep the protocol (i.e. https), and 2) what about if I just want to redirect to the parent folder, not necessarily the root?

Comment: Meaning http://www.domain.com/app/dir1/ -> http://www.domain.com/app/ and http://app.domain.com/dir1/ -> http://app.domain.com/ (consider that app.domain.com has the DocumentRoot in /home/domain/www/app/ )

Comment: Re (1): there is a HTTPS variable which contains the string "on" if the connection is SSL. The most straightforward way to use this would be to split the rule into two that have a RewriteCond based on HTTPS containing "on" and not containing "on", and each going to https or http, respectively.

Comment: I'm revising the answer, because it's not the best way.

Comment: Re (2): I don't see an easy way to do that because the left hand side pattern match works with the local part only, and to achieve the one-level-up redirection, you need to match within the prefix above. So doing this without the help of pattern matching on the left hand side means that the string manipulation has to be done on the right hand side. Take a lookat RewriteMap. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap With RewriteMap you can have an external program (sed, perl, ...) do filtering. It is not launched for every rewrite, but just once and used as a coprocess.

Comment: I.e. you declare the RewriteMap (giving it a name and indicating that it's via an external script) and then there is a syntax for referring to that map inside the right hand side of a rule to filter a variable.  The left hand side doesn't give you the full text you need, so you have to get it from some request-related variables like REQUEST_URI. E.g.  `${myperlmap:$REQUEST_URI}`. Good luck with that if you try it.

Comment: Re: (1) again: I think it's not an issue in the redirect to `/`.

Comment: Man, every time I get into `mod_rewrite` it is like this. I can guarantee you that the next time I need to muck around with this my self, six, 12 or 18 months down the line, I will have forgotten everything and will have to re-learn it.

Comment: Yeah, it is not the most intuitive system or easy to remember. Well, thanks! (specially for Re(2) :D)